# Removing Line Separator between two cells in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, controls

I am doing some **WinForms** work, for **DataGridView** I have to show blank text for some cells in Grid Header, I want to remove the Line separator to give a user feel like its a single cell.

I will attach a screen-shot for the tentative design, at the moment I did what, Added a panel on to that line, Its fine if I have no re-size-able windows,but when i switch my application to dynamic re-sizing, that shadow panel goes dis-aligned . Kindly suggest any idea how to fix it through coding.
[image: Below is the Image]

Comment: you should override the `CellPainting` event of the DataGridView to do this. Note `RowIndex` of header row is `-1`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2063971/1997232) could be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have sucessfully done this code after code modifications.

The solution is to do all the stuff in **_Paint** event.

```
        dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
        Rectangle headerRect = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(dataGridView1.Columns["phone"].Index, -1, true); //get the column header cell
        headerRect.X = headerRect.X + headerRect.Width-2;
        headerRect.Y += 1;
        headerRect.Width = 2*2;
        headerRect.Height -= 2;
        DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn = dataGridView1.Columns["<Column>"];
        Color cl; 
        cl = dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(cl), headerRect);
```