# How to merge cells in VB.net Data Grid View with equal values from SQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

here are my example cells

[image]

it should be like this one

[image]

here is my code for filling my data grid

```
    con.Open()
    Dim query As String = "select * from tbllogin"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)
    Dim rd As SqlDataReader
    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader

    DGV.Columns.Clear()
    DGV.Rows.Clear()

    DGV.Columns.Add("col1", "UserName")
    DGV.Columns.Add("col2", "Password")

    While rd.Read
        DGV.Rows.Add(rd("UserName").ToString, rd("Password").ToString)
    End While

    rd.Close()
    con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to merge cells in DataGridView. You need to manually alter the way the grid painted and that is not a fun work :(

Some questions already asked addressing similar requirement :

- [How to Merge DataGridView Cell in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774966/how-to-merge-datagridview-cell-in-winform-of-c-sharp-2008)
- [Merge cells in datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063951/merge-cells-in-datagridview)