# How to add a column of One row of same size in datagridview?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, datatables, datagridviewcolumn

I have created a Data Grid View in Visual studio using c#.  It has three columns.  Now I want to add a new column at the end containing list data.  Column with one row of size of the Data Grid View table. Grayed one in the image I have created yellow part I have to add.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524075/programatically-add-new-column-to-datagridview

Comment: Share your code of how you are adding new column.

Comment: You may want to peruse… [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: To get "*one row*" the size of the `DataGridView.Rows`, you will need to manually merge the cells yourself using the `OnPaint` event. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2063951/3773066) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16774966/3773066).

Comment: Thank you ohBeWise.

Answer (score 0):

You could to do not draw a Top border for that column. Something like this:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 3 && e.RowIndex > 1)
        {
            e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
        }
    }
```